# ¿Como seleccionar, solo 2 campos de la relacion(NestJS, TypeORM, PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, relaciones, nestjs, typeorm

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
async findAll() {
    return await this.postRepository.find({
        relations: ['media_posts'],
        select: ['id', 'title', 'post_date', 'description']
    })
}
```

Todo bien hasta ahi, pero me devuelve todos los campos de media_posts y **solo** quisiera obtener el campo *id* y *name* (por una cuestión de seguridad no quiero mostrar el campo *path* y *md5*).

Muchas gracias de antemano.